# Crawling Web and Stored Links

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

I want to create a thread in order to crawl all links of a website and store it in `LinkedHashSet`, but when I print the size of this `LinkedHashSet`, it prints nothing. I've started learning crawling! I've referenced The Art of Java. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestThread {

    public void crawl(URL url) {
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            LinkedHashSet toCrawlList = new LinkedHashSet();

            while (line != null) {
                toCrawlList.add(line);
                System.out.println(toCrawlList.size());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TestThread test1 = new TestThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run(){
               try {
                   test1.crawl(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
               } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(TestThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }
           } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to get all linked that i've been crawled and stored it , i just using a LinkHashSet in order to store , but when i crawedl and print out , it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should fill your list like this:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   toCrawlList.add(line);
}
System.out.println(toCrawlList.size());
```

If that doesn't work, try to set a break point in your code and find out if your reader even contains anything.